# MongoDB updating field contained in subdocument throws an error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My collection schema looks like this:

```
Products :{ _id: "S2oF6HitSKzwy5toz",
            user_id: "LKAHKhK5SvTr6r8sK",
            shop: "eBay.com",
            items: {
                    item: "HP Laptop"
                    item_total: 101.67
                    notes: "note for hp laptop"
                    price: 101.67
                    quantity: 1
                    shop: "eBay.com"
                    url: "ebay.com/hp"
                    },
            expenses: {
                       bank_fee: 0
                       cod_fee: 0
                       expense_total: 0
                       inbound_fee: 0
                       pcs_fee: 0
                       pjp_fee: 0
                      },
            service_fee: 15.25,
            total: 116.92
           }
```

I want to update `bank_fee` field in the `expenses` subdocument using `update` query using this syntax:

```
insertFee : function(user_id, id, fee_amount){
    Products.update({user_id: user_id, _id: id}, {$set: {"expenses.$.bank_fee":fee_amount}});
}
```

However it throws the error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'insertFee' MongoError: can't append to array us
ing string field name [$]
```

What I am doing wrong here?

P.S. I am following [this doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/) for update operation.

Comment: `expenses` is not an array. Do you mean to update `expenses.bank_fee`?

Comment: @Thilo Yes. I want to update `expenses.bank_fee`.

Comment: does `$set: {"expenses.bank_fee": fee_amount}` work then?

Comment: No, using `$set: {"expenses.bank_fee": fee_amount}` throws same error : `MongoError: can't append to array us
ing string field name [bank_fee]`.

Comment: the expenses isn't an array so you can use dot notation without the '$'

Comment: @sohelkhalifa is the expenses exactly as shown above? is it with a `[]` in wrapped around there too?

Comment: @Akshat. You mean dot notation as `$set: {expenses.bank_fee: fee_amount};`, right?

Comment: Are you sure the document looks like shown above? Why does the error message keep talking about arrays?

Comment: @sohelkhalifa yes but it looks like your document is something like expenses is an array right? you want to use something like `$addToSet : {"expenses": {bank_fee:xxx,cod_fee:yyy,inbound_fee:zzzz}}` to add each one in if thats the intention

Comment: of note is the `$` hasn't come to meteor yet you have to use the actual index number instead such as `expenses.0.bank_fee`

Comment: I made a mistake while creating default `expenses` subdocument. I want it as an Object, while I created it as an array. Anyways, it is fixed now. Thanks folks for helping. :-)